# Amazon S3 Access Control List and Amazon SDK for .NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

I have an ASP.NET MVC 3 app that uses Amazon S3 to store movie files. Right now everything is public so I can access the files. Let's say I wanted to share these videos but only if people purchased a subscription to my website (on register). How would I go about making the videos private and only allowing registered users to access this amazon URL?

Can I do this without making my subscribers sign up for an Amazon account?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you make your files private, you can generate time limited urls to your files for your members. Its easy to [generate these urls](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/sdkfornet/latest/apidocs/html/M_Amazon_S3_AmazonS3Client_GetPreSignedURL.htm) using the SDK for .NET

Or you could use [Amazons Identity and Access Management (IAM)](http://aws.amazon.com/iam/) service to restrict access to the files based on some criteria.